# Extend blueprint in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way to extend blueprints in EmberJS? As far as I know, I can [*override* a blueprint](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/blueprints/#definingacustomblueprint):

> Blueprints in your project’s directory take precedence over those packaged with Ember CLI. This makes it easy to override the built-in blueprints by generating one with the same name.

But it seems I have to copy-paste some JS and the template itself. I would like to change the default template a bit, without breaking the actual template and template behavior.

By example, let's say I would like to replace only one line in [this template](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/blueprints/controller-test/qunit-rfc-232-files/__root__/__testType__/__path__/__test__.js):

```js
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupTest } from 'ember-qunit';

module('<%= friendlyTestDescription %>', function(hooks) {
  setupTest(hooks);

  // TODO: Replace this with your real tests.
  test('it exists', function(assert) {
    let controller = this.owner.lookup('controller:<%= controllerPathName %>');
    assert.ok(controller);
  });
});
```

I would like to change only one line (`let` vs `const`:

```js
    const controller = this.owner.lookup('controller:<%= controllerPathName %>');
```

I don't want to rewrite the whole [index file](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/blueprints/controller-test/index.js) plus the blueprint template file, it seems overkill. Is it possible?

Comment: Be the change you want to see. Open an issue here: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs